# Начало текста становится ссылкой

Tags: php, html

Короче, у меня есть функция, задача которой с помощью регулярки ловить ссылки в тексте и заменять их на кликабельные. Проблема в том, что начало текста тоже становится ссылкой.

Вот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема была в верстке, div с текстом обернут в ссылку, которая ведет на пост. Если ссылку убрать, проблема исчезает, но как перейти на страницу поста не понятно.

```
<a href="{{route('userPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}"><div>{!!$post->message!!}</div></a>
```

Comment: Проблема в том что здесь `{!!$post->message!!}` у вас вставляется html фрагмент с сылками и увас ломается верстка. Усли вывести текст так `{{ $post->message }}` то скорее всего все будет нормально, но в тексте появятся теги. Вам нужно либо с `{!!$post->message!!}` убрать ссылки, либо сделать как то так `<div>{!!$post->message!!}</div><a href="{{route('userPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}">Просмотреть</a>`. В целом использование конструкции `{!! !!}` в шаблонах не желательно так во первых это может поламать верстку (ваш случай), во вторых можно вставить вредоносный js скрипт

Comment: Я понимаю что использовать !! не безопасно, но как допустим в вк ссылки обрабатываются при публикации сообщения?

Comment: Ну не думаю что вк гдето пытается вставить ссылку в ссылку так как это делаете вы. Одно дело блок с сообщением где есть ссылки и другое дело ссылка на сообщение.